# Does WP10 SDK allow targetting WP8.1 as well?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, win-universal-app

When installing Visual Studio 2015, there are mobile development options for "Universal Windows App" (i.e. including Windows Phone 10), and 
"Windows Phone 8.0/8.1".

Right now, the majority of devices are on 8.1.

**Does the WP10 SDK also backward target 8.1, or is it only for WP10?**

In other words, if for now I want to target 8.1, can I install SDK10 and rely on backwards compatibility, or must I install SDK8 as well? (They are each over 10GB in size!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Windows 10 SDK does not support creating projects that target Windows Phone 8.1 devices, nor can UWP apps run on 8.1 devices. You will need the WP8.1 SDK so you can develop WinRT 8.1 projects that will run on Windows Phone 8.1.

For what it is worth, WinRT 8.1 apps in general should be able to run on Windows 10 devices with no major issues. I know for one that my WP8.1 app works just fine on Windows 10 Mobile build 10586.164, albeit with minor UI inconsistencies. But mine is a relatively simple app; YMMV depending on your projects.

For the best user experience, of course, building a version for each OS version is your best bet, and with a decent MVVM architecture you should only have to create unique XAML views (and maybe view models) for each OS without having to port the rest of your business logic much, if at all (since UWP is basically a newer version of WinRT). I will post an update to my question [here on Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293722/how-can-i-target-both-windows-10-uwp-and-windows-phone-8-1-in-the-same-app) once I ship the Windows 10 version of my app, at which point I'll have more information on this process.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know. Pity the SDKs are not cumulative.

Comment: I'm doing cross-platform using Xamarin, so I have `Foo.Android` and `Foo.iOS` projects. I was planning on adding `Foo.WP8` and `Foo.WP10` projects. From your answer, I take it that I'll need to install SDK8 and SDK10 to do that.

Comment: @hbob: I believe that is the case. I'm not currently using Xamarin, but a skim through the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation) seems to confirm this since it basically involves adding the respective project types, which require the respective SDKs.